# Curved text Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to create curved text in Jetpack Compose like it was in "Material You". But how?
Example:
[image: clock]

Comment: What do you mean "Material" You? You think now I'm not material but more Spiritual?

Comment: @MARSK "Material You" - new design system that was introduced in Google I/O 2021.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for the knowledge,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using `Canvas`. Compose itself does not have a function to draw a curved text (afaik in rc-01). But using `drawIntoCanvas` function you can use the `nativeCanvas` which provides `drawTextOnPath` where you can draw a text in a `Path`. In this `Path` you add an arc, so your text is drawn in this path.

```kotlin
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(300.dp)
        .background(Color.Gray)
) {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        val textPadding = 48.dp.toPx()
        val arcHeight = 400.dp.toPx()
        val arcWidth = 300.dp.toPx()
        val path = Path().apply {
            addArc(0f, textPadding, arcWidth, arcHeight, 180f, 180f)
        }
        it.nativeCanvas.drawTextOnPath(
            "Curved Text with Jetpack Compose",
            path,
            0f,
            0f,
            Paint().apply {
                textSize = 16.sp.toPx()
                textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: How do I regulate the size of the Text here?

Comment: It is negligible in my case