# Curved TextField in JC?

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

We can get a curved text in JC by using native canvas, how about a textfield?

So I have this wicked workaround, where I would control the keyboard state, then whatever the user types, I'll just update the curved text. Like a custom text field. Ok so how I gonna do this? I need callbacks for keyboard presses, which I assume I can get from onKeyChange Modifiers. I need to know a way to get and set the keyboard state. So yeah the former is what I do not know how.

Anyway, that is not what I am asking about (though it would be nice if someone answered that as well). This is a workaround born in my brainstorming brain, but is there a neat way of doing it? Also, any workaround that is a little less dirty than this? All suggestions welcome

What I mean by 'curved': [Curved text Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68414966/15880865)

Only it should be a TextField instead of text

Comment: Could you try to specify curved? Maybe a screenshot of your designers idea? Right now i am imagining some kind of WordArt, which would be wild to implement

Comment: Yes exactly. That wordart sort of thingy, but it is easy to implement upon text, and even on TextField with my wicked workaround, but I am basically asking for a cleaner one if there is. Thanks. With my workaround, you can achieve literally any shape you want — even random scribble.